# DELETE query to destroy all but most recent and every first record every month within group of records

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I would like to create an `SQL DELETE` query that in one statement deletes all but:

- the most recent record
- and all but first record each previous month

within a group of records. I made an SQL fiddle example here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2272a

The result of the delete should be, that from the group og records (records having `other_table_id = 1`), the only ones left should be:

```
('2017-01-02', 1), 
('2017-03-24', 1),
('2017-04-03', 1), 
('2017-05-24', 1),
('2017-12-14', 1)
```

Is this at all possible to do in one query or do I need to do it in multiple ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate your conditions pretty directly into a `delete` statement.  Here is one method:

```
delete from example_table et
    where et.created_at < (select max(et2.created_at) from example_table et2 where et2.other_table_id = et.other_table_id) and
          et.created_at not in (select min(et2.created_at) from example_table et2 where et2.other_table_id = et.other_table_id and et2.created_at is not null group by to_char(et2.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'))
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/baf84/1).

EDIT:

I see.  Your question says "previous month".  This query does what you want:

```
delete from example_table et
    where et.created_at < (select max(et2.created_at) from example_table et2 where et2.other_table_id = et.other_table_id) and
          et.created_at not in (select min(et2.created_at)
                                from example_table et2
                                where et2.other_table_id = et.other_table_id and et2.created_at is not null and
                                      date_trunc('month', et2.created_at) <> (select date_trunc('month', max(et3.created_at)) from example_table et3) 
                                group by to_char(et2.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
                               );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9ea33/1) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Is it just me, or isn't this working? I don't see it deleting anything in the fiddle :-)

Comment: Hi again, thanks. Now it's running. However, the solution has the same problem as the one suggested by @DineshDB currently. It keeps the wrong record for the most recent month (2017-12-10 instead of 2017-12-14). This was not not visible from the first seed data I created, however I updated the data to expose this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5b922/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM example_table
WHERE ID NOT IN(
  SELECT ID FROM(
  select id
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_part('year',created_at),date_part('month',created_at) ORDER BY ID)Rn 
    from example_table WHERE other_table_id =1
    )D
  WHERE RN=1);

  SELECT * FROM example_table;
```

[# SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0338f/20)

Comment: Actually, second thought :-) Now that I'm implementing it, I'm seeing two flaws: 1. we need to invert the id selection to avoid it deleting from the other groups (other_table_id = 2, 3 and 4). 2. If I alter the seed data slightly, we can see that the first criteria `the most recent record` is actually not fulfilled. It keeps the first record from the most recent month as well! In this case that is the record with `2017-12-10` instead of `2017-12-14`. That one I don't know how to solve...? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2272a/14